# Update User Entity Framework

Tags: entity-framework-4, asp.net-membership

I am writing an asp.net membership provider using Entity code first and I need some help understanding how to Update the MembershipUser object.

The UpdateUsert(MembershipUser user) override method needs to be implemented and consists of a MembershipUser parameter.

The following code does not work and I am not sure how to tie the MembershipDBContext with the supplied membership user so that the user is updated.  Thanks for the help.

```
public override void UpdateUser(MembershipUser user)
{
    MembershipDBModel userToUpdate = _getMembershipDBModelUser(user.UserName);

    userToUpdate.IsLockedOut = user.IsLockedOut;


    using (MembershipDBContext db = new MembershipDBContext())
    {
        db.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

Comment: You're reinventing the membership API. [Don't do this](http://blogs.teamb.com/craigstuntz/2010/03/05/38558/).

Answer (score 1):

Why not use the built in functionality for the MembershipProvider?

```
MembershipUser user = Membership.GetUser();
user.IsApproved = false;
Membership.UpdateUser(user);
```

Comment: Because I am creating a custom membership provider and need to implement the update UpdateUser(user) method.

Comment: Even so, you should follow the base functionality. http://www.asp.net/general/videos/how-do-i-create-a-custom-membership-provider

Comment: I am writing my OWN save methods. Calling Membership.UpdateUser() does nothing because no code exists.  I am overriding that method.

Comment: Also the user.IsLockedOut property is read only in this context which is also problematic.  My approach was to get the record from my db update it and return it.  Maybe I am missing a concept or something but i am not following you.

Comment: @ChiliYago, good point. The lockout should be used for password failures, and the IsApproved field for this scenario.